# jquery jqgrid hide colums code behind

Tags: jquery

I have started using jqgrid in my asp.net application.

Asp.net, c#

I want to know how can i show/hide columns via code behind.

I have this:

I have a user preference table where I would store a users grid column preference in the table.

Now based on this preference I want to show/hide my columns in the grid.

Is this possible via jquery jgrid.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JQGrid1.Columns.FromDataField("ColumnDataField").Visible = false;
```